# Windows Phone browser with Ad-block support

Tags: windows-phone, ad-blocker

There is seemingly no Windows Phone 8.1 browsers with existing Ad-blocking add-on, or build-in ad-blocker. Is my search hopeless, or is there such browser? The only thing that came close is the hack in this thread

http://forum.xda-developers.com/windows-phone-8/development/mod-ad-blocker-t3029487

however I would like something less 'drastic'